# Prove that all numbers $10^n + 1$ are square free

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is this possible to prove? I've seen some patterns in the prime factorizations of these numbers, and would like to know if it is possible to prove this.

Comment: Maybe you meant that it isn't perfect square?

Comment: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IA/Numbers+Sets/2014-2015/examples-NS-14-2.pdf
By any chance are you looking at Q13?

Comment: has the OP gone to sleep?

Comment: See [OEIS A$128683$](http://oeis.org/A128683).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No: $10^{11} + 1$ is divisible by $11^2$.

Comment: If one checks a lot more of those numbers, one finds [11, 21, 33, 39, 55, 63, ...](https://oeis.org/A086982).

Comment: @Dr.MV It's the smallest number such that $10^n+1$ is divisible by perfect square in this instance it's divisible by $11^2$ when $n=11$ also on a side note $10^n+1$ can never be a perfect square.

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks!  Interesting.  Forgive me for being naïve here, but how does one show that rigorously?

Comment: @Dr.MV $10^n+1\equiv2\mod3$.

Comment: $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo 3.

Comment: $1^2\equiv1\mod3$, $2^2\equiv1\mod3$, $3^2\equiv0\mod3$. It wasn't so difficult, was it?

Comment: @Dr.MV Try squaring $3n, 3n+1, 3n+2$ and see what remainders do they give on divison by $3$? :)

Comment: @Sawarnik Thanks for the reply!  So, let me see if I understand.  Since any integer $m$ is equal to either $3n$, $3n+1$, or $3n+2$, for some $n$, then the square of any number can be found accordingly.  And since none of the square of those numbers has remainder $2$ after dividing by $3$, then $3n+2$ is never a square of any other number.  I actually tried doing this, but somehow wrote $3n+2 = 3(n+1)-1$ and didn't think about the absurdity of interpreting $-1$ as remainder $1$.  A brain meltdown.  So, do I have it now?

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, you have it :)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Ah, didn't realize that was covered in the OEIS. I just told WolframAlpha to spit out the first exception.

Answer (score 0):

$10^n+1$ is never a perfect square. $n$ must be odd. We have:
$$10^n =c^2-1=(c+1)(c-1)$$
One of $(c+1)$ and $(c-1)$ must be a multiple of $10$, as otherwise we cannot introduce factors of $2$. And it must not have $100$ as a factor, otherwise the other number must be $2$.

and so w.l.o.g. we hsve say $c+1=2\times 5^n$ and $c-1=2^{n-1}$. But this is clearly impossible as $5^n\gt\gt2^{n-1}$.

Comment: A number can be square-free without being a perfect square.

Comment: I think OP meant no squares not squarefree.

Comment: An easier way to prove this would be to say that $10^n+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, which can never be a square.

Comment: @JerryGuol or that both $c-1$ and $c+1$ can only contain factors of $2$ or $5$.