# Square-free integer

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that for any positive integer, the prime decomposition of N = 10^2n + 10^n + 1 is of the form N = p*q*r*s*... with distinct numbers p < q < r < s <...?

For the first values of n,hereafter the prime decompositions:

n = 1, N = 111 = 3*37

n = 2, N = 10101 = 3*7*13*37

n = 3, N = 1001001 = 3*333667

n = 4, N = 100010001 = 3*7*13*37*9901

n = 5, N = 10000100001 = 3*31*37*2906161

n = 6, N = 1000001000001 = 3*19*52579*333667

n = 7, N = 100000010000001 = 3*37*43*1933*10838689

n = 8, N = 10000000100000001 = 3*7*13*37*9901*99990001
etc....

Answer (score 3):

No, for $n=14$ we have
$$
10^{2n}+10^n+1=3^1\cdot 7^2\cdot 13\cdot 37\cdot 43\cdot 127\cdot 1933\cdots .
$$
So this number is not squarefree. In principle, we have seen this question here, a bit differently:

[Prove that all numbers $10^n + 1$ are square free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188750/prove-that-all-numbers-10n-1-are-square-free)

This claim also was not true.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thank you, Oscar.

Answer (score 2):

We set out to find a counterexample that is divisible by $49$, using a method similar to that demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154578/3p-2p-squarefree/3154865#3154865).

First solve $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\bmod 49$.  Thereby $x\in\{18,30\}\bmod 49$, both of these residues being units.  Now we must put in $x=10^n$ and determine whether some whole number $n$ gives $x\in\{18,30\}\bmod 49$.

The residue $3$ is a primitive root $\bmod 7$.  Then among the units $\bmod 49$ the only *nonprimitive* residue $\equiv 3\bmod 7$ is $3^7\equiv 31\bmod 49$.  Since $10$ is different from this solutions to $10^n\in\{18,30\} \bmod 49$ must exist and with them, so do multiples of $49$ matching $10^{2n}+10^n+1$.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanations.

Comment: May I say that if I consider N = 3^(2*3^n) + 3^(3^n) + 1, N is not square-free for some integers n?

Comment: Ask a new question, please.